# Return the error message from AWS Lambda through AWS API HTTP Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an Amazon API HTTP Gateway integrated with an AWS Lambda. In some cases, the lambda can return errors with error messages. In these cases, I would like that the API returns the lambda error instead of `Status 500, {"message": "Internal Server Error"}`. Lambda errors have the format:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Error message of the lambda",
  "errorType": "lambda_failure",
  "stackTrace": [...]
}
```

How can I change the integration response to obtain `Status 500, {"error": "Error message of the lambda"}`?

Answer (score 1):

You can return errors from Lambda by returning an object with the following format in Lambda.

```
{
  "isBase64Encoded" : "boolean",
  "statusCode": "number", // Represents the HTTP status code
  "headers": { ... }, // Represents the response headers
  "body": "JSON string" // Represents the body of the response
}
```

For example, if you want API Gateway (backed by AWS Lambda) to send an 404 (Not Found) error, you should return like so in your Lambda function:

```rb
# Below is a Ruby code

return {
  statusCode: 500,
  body: {
    message: "An error occurred"
  }.to_json
}
```

References:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html

Comment: Thanks, I know that option. But I'd rather change the integration response.